# How to make a running service that not disturbing the activity?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-manifest, android-service

i have an activity called wipeScreen.java

this activity runs a wipeService.java for wiping a SMS and a contacts on android mobile phone. when a wipeService running, my wipeScreen activity is stuck and can't be used, only showing a black screen, and even give me some "force close" for long waiting time..

has anyone know how to create a service that can be self-working and not disturbing the activity so the activity still can be used when the service is running??

here's my wipescreen trigger code:

```
SPWipe = getSharedPreferences("wipe", 0);
editorSPWipe = SPWipe.edit();
editorSPWipe.putString("wipe", "yes");
editorSPWipe.commit();

intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,WipeScreenForm.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

here's my wipeScreen code:

```
        SPtempWipe = getSharedPreferences("wipe", 0);
        if (SPtempWipe.getString("wipe","").equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            startService(new Intent(LockScreenForm.this, WipeService.class));
            SPWipe = getSharedPreferences("wipe", 0);
            editorSPWipe = SPWipe.edit();
            editorSPWipe.putString("wipe", "no");
            editorSPWipe.commit();
        }
```

and here's my wipeService code :

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        wipeSMS();
        wipeContact();
        stopService(new Intent(this, WipeService.class));
    }


    public void wipeSMS()
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null,
          null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            try {
                long thread_id = cursor.getLong(1);
                Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/"
                   + thread_id);
                getContentResolver().delete(thread, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

    public void wipeContact() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            try{
                String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
                cr.delete(uri, null, null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
```

when a service started to removing my contact, the wipeScreen activity is stuck and can't be used.. please help me to make this service started without disturbing the wipeScreen activity.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to run your code in a separate thread

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Fredrik.. i'll try it first.. have a nice day.. :)\